# How to skip nopcommerce installation?

Tags: nopcommerce

I have deployed my project on the server and also exported the database on the server.

Now I would like to skip the installation. How is it possible?

I tried to put the 'Settings.txt' file in App_Data and also the 'InstalledPlugins.txt', but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

'Settings.txt' needs to be updated with new SQL Database in your PROD server. Just copying over will not help. If you just copy over, then NopCommerce from PROD will look for Database in your local or dev PC which is not accessible (in most cases)

'Settings.txt' stores db connection as ADO.Net connection string. so you can edit easily.